# Saving groups of commands for later use in perl script

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver, www-mechanize

I'm working on my first Perl script here and trying to be as efficient as possible by re-using code instead of having the same code over and over. I've tried a couple different things already to no avail.

I'm also trying to avoid having to just import the set of commands from an external file, but it's looking like the only viable option right now. So I'm seeking advice here.

Here is the gist of the script (taking advantage of Selenium):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
use WWW::Selenium;

my @changepass;
my $addsub     = '';
my $add2sub    = '';

GetOptions (
    "changepass|cp=s{3}" => \@changepass,
    "addsub|as=s" => \$addsub,
    "add2sub|a2s=s" => \$add2sub,
    "help|h" => \&do_help
) or die(&do_help);


sub login {
  my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new(
      host => "localhost",
      port => 4444,
      browser => "*googlechrome",
      browser_url => "example.com",
  );
  $sel->start;
  $sel->open("/login.php");
  $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("5000");
  $sel->type("id=loginSection-username", "username");
  $sel->type("id=loginSection-password", "password");
  $sel->click("name=send");
  $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");
  sleep(2);

  return $sel;
}


sub do_changepass {
  my $email = $changepass[0];
  my $oldpass = $changepass[1];
  my $newpass = $changepass[2];
  my ($sel) = @_;
  $sel->click("css=#my-webspaces-container .more > a");
  $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");
  ...MORE COMMANDS...
}


if (@changepass) {
  print "Changing password...\n";
  my $sel = do_changepass();
  print "Finished!\n";
}
```

So I'd like to be able to reuse certain blocks of code such as the `my $sel` variable. But I do realize it's an object. If I could somehow just store it as plain text and then import it into the function. (not via an external file, if possible.)

Comment: Please don't completely change your question. It puts answers and comments you got before the change out of context. One of the primary functions of Stack Overflow is to provide reusable solutions for other people to access, and you should avoid anything that makes the post less comprehensible over all. You can always *add* to your answer to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get working what you're trying to accomplish you have to take care about the scope of the $sel Object:

```
...

if (@commands){
    my $sel = login();
    do_changepass($sel);
}

sub login {
    my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                                  port => 4444,
                                  browser => "*googlechrome",
                                  browser_url => "example.com",
                                );
    $sel->start;
    $sel->open("/login.php");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("5000");
    $sel->type("id=loginSection-username", "username");
    $sel->type("id=loginSection-password", "password");
    $sel->click("name=send");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");
    sleep(2);

    return $sel;
}

sub do_changepass {
    my $email = $changepass[0]; my $oldpass = $changepass[1]; my $newpass = $changepass[2];
    my ($sel) = @_;
    $sel->click("css=#my-webspaces-container .more > a");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");
    ...MORE COMMANDS...
}
...
```

`my` creates the  variable with a lexical scope, so it will be gone after you leave the current block (and there are no references to it neither).

or you can use the `login`-subroutine directly in the `do_changepass`

```
...
    sub do_changepass {
        my $email = $changepass[0]; my $oldpass = $changepass[1]; my $newpass = $changepass[2];
        my ($sel) = login(); # <--- login used here!!!
        $sel->click("css=#my-webspaces-container .more > a");
        $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");
        ...MORE COMMANDS...
    }
...
```

Comment: The second option is exactly what I was looking for. This works a treat. Thank you! Two questions though, can you elaborate on that the parenthesis mean when defining the variable? And would it be possible to add more functions in.. i.e. `my ($sel) = login() . go2page();`

Comment: Every subroutine takes a list (NOT an array!) of arguments and also returns a list. `(listitem0, listitem1,...) = subroutine(listitem0, listitem1,...)`. when i assign a list to a scalar (`$somthing`) it assings the first listitem by default. So when you return only 1 scalar from the sub, `my $xyz = lala()` is equivalent to `my ($xyz) = lala()`. When you return more values: `my ($val1, $val2) = lala()`

Comment: What do you mean by adding more functions? Like in boxing them? `my $sel = go2page(login());`

Comment: There is nothing wrong woth the code as shown in the original quesion. The value of `$sel` is passed out of `login` and saved by the caller, then passed into `do_changepass`. It will not be discarded anywhere.

Comment: well in the OPs code above `do_changepass`neither receives nor returns  `$sel`...

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I hadn't realized he had completely changed the question!

Comment: Yeah. The problem was actually that he never called `login` at all!

Comment: Borodin I appreciate your answer and it was very helpful. I would of marked your correct had marderh not answered before you updated yours. @marderh I'm not sure what you mean by boxing functions in, but what I want to do is make the functions sort of modular. Like I have the login function, which logs into the page.. then I might have a function like `goto_pass_page()`. So my `do_changepass()` function would then have both the `login()` and `goto_pass_page()` functions. Hopefully that explains it better.

Comment: @Brandon `sub do_changepass { my $sel = login(); $sel = goto_pass_page($sel); }  sub goto_pass_page {my ($sel) = @_; .... return $sel}` and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Note that you should *never* put prototypes on Perl subroutines (the `()` after the subroutine identifier). You must also *always* add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of *every* program. (`use warnings` is preferable to `-w` in the shebang line.)

You can return the `$sel` object that you have created in one subroutine and use it further in another. It's not clear what sort of thing you want to do as your two subroutines appear to be identical apart from a comment at the end of the second, but this may help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Selenium;

sub login {
  my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new(
      host => "localhost",
      port => 4444,
      browser => "*googlechrome",
      browser_url => "example.com",
  );
  $sel->start;
  $sel->open("/login.php");
  $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("5000");
  $sel->type("id=username", "usernamehere");
  $sel->type("id=password", "passwordhere");
  $sel->click("name=send");
  $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");
  sleep(2);

  return $sel;
}

sub some_function {
  my ($sel) = @_;
  # ....MORE COMMANDS HERE....
}

my $sel = login();
some_function($sel);
```

---

**Update**

What you have wrong with your code is that you never call `login`. If you look at my example above, `login` is called to do the login and return the value of `$sel`, which is then passed to `some_function`.

Your code should look like this

```
if (@changepass) {
  print "Changing password...\n";
  my $sel = login();
  do_changepass($sel);
  print "Finished!\n";
}
```

I also suggest that you avoid calling `login` from within each subroutine. It is best called from the same code that calls `do_changepass` etc. as above.

Comment: Borodin, I've updated my code to be more to the point of what I'm trying to accomplish. And as you can see I've also tried what your suggesting but it's not working. Failing with `Can't call method click` probably because it's not picking up on `$sel`.

Comment: Basically, every function must include this "login routine" before going navigating any further in the page. So `do_changepass()` has to perform the login routine first and then perform it's own steps.

Comment: @Brandon: You misunderstood my initial solution and implemented it wrongly. I have added to my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, one of the best things you can do to avoid duplication as well as increase maintainability is to introduce abstraction.

In order to reuse your "selenium" instance throughout the script here is what I do:

In my test script:

```
my $driver = Custom::WebApp::setup_selenium( undef, undef, \%desired_capabilities );
```

In my WebApp.pm:

```
sub setup_selenium {

    my $self         = shift;
    my $browser      = shift;
    my $capabilities = shift;
    my $driver;
    my %desired_capabilities;

    if ($capabilities) {
        %desired_capabilities = %$capabilities;
    }

    # Start selenium with capabilities if passed in from test script
    unless ( keys %desired_capabilities == 0 ) {

        $driver = eval {
            Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(%desired_capabilities);
        };
        return $@ if $@;    # Return with error if capability not matched
    }

    # Or just start it with default settings
    else {
        $driver = eval {
            Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( browser_name => $browser,
                                           proxy => { proxyType => 'system' } );
        };
        return $@ if $@;    # Return with error if capability not matched
    }
    return $driver;

}
```

The driver that is returned by `setup_selenium` can then be used throughout the script until you call `$driver->quit;`

If you notice, the above solution is using Selenium::Remote::Driver binding but you can easily replace WWW::Selenium if you like (although I do recommend S:R:D mainly because it's actively maintained on Git and CPAN).